# How to write unicode value to a file using java?

Tags: java, unicode, properties

I am trying to update my property files using java.I am not using java.util.Properties as it changes the order of the keys .
I have created my own logic to write the keys in order .

I am using File IO to read/write properties.
The problem i am facing is ,when i write the Japanese strings to the file,I need to unicode value of the String to be written.

Input :さん
Expected value in file :\u3055\u3093
Value that is saved :さん

Code:

```
String strJapanese = "日本語";

try {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.utf");

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(fos,"UTF-8"));
    bufferedWriter.write(strJapanese);
    bufferedWriter.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

I have also tried setting the encoding format to 8859_1 as done by Properties class.
The Properties class automatically converts the japaneese string to unicode characters while storing it to the files.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want the characters that represent Java Unicode escape sequences to be written to the file?

Comment: Have you also tried `new OutputStreamWriter(fos,"UTF8")`, that might be different.

Comment: @TedHopp yes i want the Unicode escape sequences to be written to the file .I want these values "\u3055\u3093" to be written.Instead the Japanese values are getting stored .

Comment: @AlvinBunk yes i did.No luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils#escapeJava()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)), that will give you Java escaped string.

```
String escaptedStrJapanese = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("日本語");
//then write it 
bufferedWriter.write(escaptedStrJapanese);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Unicode escape sequences to be written to the file instead of the characters themselves, you will need to do the conversion yourself. Using UTF-8 encoding is not the right tool (you can use it with no harm, but it won't help). You should also move the call to `close()` to a `finally` block:

```
String strJapanese = "日本語";
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("test.utf");
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    int len = strJapanese.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        bufferedWriter.write(String.format("\\u%04x", strJapanese.codePointAt(i)));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
} finally {
    if (bufferedWriter != null) {
        try {
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not close file: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `*.properties` files must use ISO 8859-1 character encoding. Quoting from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> ...the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using Unicode escapes as defined in section 3.3 of The Java™ Language Specification; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape sequence.

So you have to use `new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "8859_1")`.

But neither `BufferedWriter` nor `OutputStreamWriter` escapes the characters. This you have to do manually.

This is how the `Properties` class does it: Following is the `Properties.saveConvert()` method from Oracle JDK 1.8.0_20:

```
/*
 * Converts unicodes to encoded &#92;uxxxx and escapes
 * special characters with a preceding slash
 */
private String saveConvert(String theString,
                           boolean escapeSpace,
                           boolean escapeUnicode) {
    int len = theString.length();
    int bufLen = len * 2;
    if (bufLen < 0) {
        bufLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    StringBuffer outBuffer = new StringBuffer(bufLen);

    for(int x=0; x<len; x++) {
        char aChar = theString.charAt(x);
        // Handle common case first, selecting largest block that
        // avoids the specials below
        if ((aChar > 61) && (aChar < 127)) {
            if (aChar == '\\') {
                outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('\\');
                continue;
            }
            outBuffer.append(aChar);
            continue;
        }
        switch(aChar) {
            case ' ':
                if (x == 0 || escapeSpace)
                    outBuffer.append('\\');
                outBuffer.append(' ');
                break;
            case '\t':outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('t');
                      break;
            case '\n':outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('n');
                      break;
            case '\r':outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('r');
                      break;
            case '\f':outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('f');
                      break;
            case '=': // Fall through
            case ':': // Fall through
            case '#': // Fall through
            case '!':
                outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append(aChar);
                break;
            default:
                if (((aChar < 0x0020) || (aChar > 0x007e)) & escapeUnicode ) {
                    outBuffer.append('\\');
                    outBuffer.append('u');
                    outBuffer.append(toHex((aChar >> 12) & 0xF));
                    outBuffer.append(toHex((aChar >>  8) & 0xF));
                    outBuffer.append(toHex((aChar >>  4) & 0xF));
                    outBuffer.append(toHex( aChar        & 0xF));
                } else {
                    outBuffer.append(aChar);
                }
        }
    }
    return outBuffer.toString();
}
```

So basically the following lines are written to the file:

```
String line =
    saveConvert(key, false, true) + "=" + saveConvert(value, false, true);
```