# Displaying all the characters in java

Tags: java, char

This is what i got

```
public class CharacterArithmeticExperiment {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char start = '1';
    for(int i = 1; i < 500;i++){
      System.out.printf("%c", start + i);
    }
  }
}
```

output:

> 23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~????????????????????????????????������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????��????????????��??????????????????????�????��???????????????????�??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

That's the problem, do i need something else to properly display this, or whats up with this, I haven't learned too much on characters, but i know darn well there's more characters than that, and i really want to see them any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The characterset o your comand line is not `UTF-8`. It is not a problem with your code

Comment: refer also to a [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/) - you are already starting at ascii 50

Comment: Characters up to 128 are identical in all charsets. The 128 to 256 differ from charset to charset. Chars above 256 are only available in Unicode/utf8

Comment: you are using which IDE or console

Comment: @iPirat That is blatantly incorrect statement. For example EBCDIC is completely different from ASCII-derived character sets. Also, Unicode and UTF-8 are different things. Unicode is a set of characters, UTF-8 is a way to represent said characters in data transmit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate through the unicode codepoints of a Java String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527856/how-can-i-iterate-through-the-unicode-codepoints-of-a-java-string)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729378/how-to-write-unicode-value-to-a-file-using-java

Comment: To learn more about the characters, visit https://unicode-table.com/en/. Note: not all characters can be displayed (End-Of-Text, Bell, Backspace, Device-Control-Four, ...).

Comment: Echoing @Jens, the problem is how the text is flowing from your program to your screen. Please [edit] your question to describe that part. Your code will work except in the range `'\uD800'` to `'\uDFFF'` because those `char` values need to be properly paired to form a character (would be in a `String`).

Answer (score 0):

The char datatype in java is based on the **ascii** values. Every character, symbol and integer is associated with a **ascii** value. In your code:

```
public class CharacterArithmeticExperiment {
public static void main(String[] args) {
char start = '1';
for(int i = 1; i < 500;i++){
  System.out.printf("%c", start + i);
}
}
}
```

Here the **ascii** value of '1' is 49. In **for** loop while adding **i** to **start** the variable **start** gets typecasted and becomes 49. So for the first iteration the value of **start+i = 50** and the character associated with the ascii value 50 is '2'. So the values get printed accordingly for the next iterations too.
So the working code for printing characters could be according to the ascii values as follows :

```
public class CharacterArithmeticExperiment {
public static void main(String[] args) {
char start = 'a';
for(int i = 0; i < 26 ;i++){
  System.out.printf("%c", start + i);
}
}
}
```

**OUTPUT :**  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

[for refering to ascii value table click here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

Comment: Replace ASCII with [UTF-16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and this would be correct. UTF-16 is one of several encoding for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. (If you ever were to write code that uses ASCII, you'd know which specification requires it. For example, [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230). Otherwise, references to ASCII are typically erroneous.)